# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError - While extracting bundle apks using BundleTool in android

Tags: android, apk, android-bundle, unsupported-class-version, app-bundle

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError:
>   com/android/tools/build/bundletool/BundleToolMain : Unsupported
>   major.minor version 52.0

I am trying to run bundletool.jar to extract apks from .aab in android studio.

Comment: what is your question ? how should we help you with only the information you've provided here ?

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when you have installed lower version of jdk and then try to run bundletool.jar which required higher version of jdk to run.

In my case I had jdk 1.7 installed and then I did to steps:

1. I updated jdk 1.7 to jdk 1.8
2. Change the jdk path in Environment Variabe "JAVA_HOME" from "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_07" to "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_231"

and everything is working fine.